# how do you subset data frame based on values in data dictionary in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
df

  Server     Model    Slot  
  server1    Cisco     1        
  server1    Cisco     2         
  server1    Cisco     3        
  server1    Cisco     4         
  server1    Cisco     8        
  server1    Cisco   Chasis
  server1    Cisco   Chasis
  server2    IBM     Slot 5        
  server2    IBM     Slot 8         
  server2    IBM     Slot 9 
  server3    Micr    Slot 22       
  server3    Micr    Slot 18        
  server3    Micr    Slot 1
  server3    Micr    Chasis 1
```

I need to subset this data frame to include only slot defined the n_slots data dict:

```
n_slots={'Cisco': 8, 'IBM':6, 'Micr':4}
```

Data frame df will have more data in the slot column but we are only interested in data configured in the n_slots dictionary.

For example Cisco has 8 in n_slots dictionary, the final data frame will only need to have data from df if Slot 1, 2,3, 4, 5,6,7,8 for Cisco.

Micr has 4 in n_slots dict, my final data frame will only need to include Slot 1 through Slot 4.

My final data frame needs to be something like this given the data frame "df" and my dict called n_slots:

```
final_df

  Server     Model    Slot  
  server1    Cisco     1        
  server1    Cisco     2         
  server1    Cisco     3        
  server1    Cisco     4         
  server1    Cisco     8        
  server2    IBM       5               
  server3    Micr      1
```

1. I need to figure out the subset the data where Slot is only 1 though 8 and "Slot 1" through "Slot 8".
2. Remove "Slot" text from the Cell Values
3. final_df should include only values defined in "n_slot" dictionary.

Comment: `Micr` has unordered slot numbers. In similar case: what if `Micr` has slot numbers in sequence `4, 18, 1, 22` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest sequence goes from 1 though 4. It could be unordered. in this case I only need to pick Micr where Slot is 1,2,3, or 4.

Comment: and in case of `4, 18, 1, 22` you would just pick `4` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, I would pick 1, and 4

Comment: You need to parse the `Slot` column to get the numbers first. Then you can just `.map` the `Model` by `n_slots` and compare that with the numeric `Slot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact logic is unclear, but you could use something like:

```
# get the slot number as numeric
slots = (df['Slot'].astype(str)
         .str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False)
         .astype(float)
        )

# map max slot number and filter rows
out = df[slots.le(df['Model'].map(n_slots)]
```

Output:

```
     Server  Model    Slot
0   server1  Cisco       1
1   server1  Cisco       2
2   server1  Cisco       3
3   server1  Cisco       4
4   server1  Cisco       8
7   server2    IBM  Slot 5
12  server3   Micr  Slot 1
```

*If you want to have an integer in the output, assign the extracted numbers to `df['Slot']` to overwrite the original strings.*

```
out = (df.assign(Slot=slots)[slots.le(df['Model'].map(n_slots))]
         .astype({'Slot': int})
      )
```

Output:

```
     Server  Model  Slot
0   server1  Cisco     1
1   server1  Cisco     2
2   server1  Cisco     3
3   server1  Cisco     4
4   server1  Cisco     8
7   server2    IBM     5
12  server3   Micr     1
```

#### edit

"* I only need to include Slot that has "Slot" text in it or integers less than 12.*"

```
slots = (df['Slot'].astype(str)
         .str.extract(r'Slot *(\d+)', expand=False)
         .astype(float)
         .fillna(pd.to_numeric(df['Slot'], errors='coerce'))
        )

out = df[slots.le(df['Model'].map(n_slots) & slots.le(12)]
```

Comment: Hahaha, your solution is so much sexier than mine. :(

Comment: @mozway, I was too quick to accept your answer. Slots data frame, I only need to include Slot that has "Slot" text in it or integers less than 12

Comment: @mozway was that meant for @user1471980?

Because, although I didn't test it, your solution looked good to me and you managed it with just a few calls---I was honestly complimenting you (and I was your first upvote)

Comment: @jesse yes sorry! wrong autocomplete :) I'll delete my comment and post it again

Comment: @user1471980 it's still not fully clear, but I added a alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the Slot column contains only numbers and not strings (but in case you can preprocess the column to extract the numbers), you can achieve your goal through a for loop.

```
dfs = []
for model, n in n_slots.items():
    dfs += [df[(df["Model"] == model) & (df["Slots"] < n)]]
result = pd.concat(dfs, axis="index")
```

Comment: @mattiatanhardini, I get TypeError '<' not supported between isntance of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @user1471980 the correct (and nicer) answer is the one provided by @mozway. In my answer here I wrote that I assumed the `Slots` column to be integer type. Otherwise, when you extract the number from the string, you have to cast it. But anyway this solution won't be ok since you need also to extract rows that have the string `"Slots"` in the corresponding field.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want something like the following.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
n_slots={'Cisco': 8, 'IBM':6, 'Micr':4}

data = {
  'Server': ['server1','server2','server3','server4','server5','server6','server7'],
  'Model': ['Cisco','IBM','Cisco','Micr','Cisco','IBM','Micr'],
  'Slot': [1,'Slot 9',3,'Chasis','Slot 5','Slot 6','Slot 22']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
#     Server  Model     Slot
# 0  server1  Cisco        1
# 1  server2    IBM   Slot 9
# 2  server3  Cisco        3
# 3  server4   Micr   Chasis
# 4  server5  Cisco   Slot 5
# 5  server6    IBM   Slot 6
# 6  server7   Micr  Slot 22
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  slot_value = row['Slot']

  # if our slot_value is a string beginning with 'Slot N'
  # extract the number
  if isinstance(slot_value, str):
    slot_num = re.findall('Slot (\d+)', slot_value)

    # convert the number to an integer
    if slot_num:
      slot_num = int(slot_num[0])

      # if the value is less than or equal to the value
      # of the corresponding 'Model', insert value back
      # into df
      if slot_num < n_slots[row['Model']]:
        df.at[index, 'Slot'] = slot_num
      # otherwise, set it to None
      else:
        df.at[index, 'Slot'] = None
    else:
      df.at[index, 'Slot'] = None
  # if our slot_value is ALREADY a number
  elif isinstance(slot_value, (int, float)):
    # check value against dic value
    if slot_value < n_slots[row['Model']]:
      df.at[index, 'Slot'] = int(slot_value)
    # otherwise set it to None
    else:
      df.at[index, 'Slot'] = None
  else:
    df.at[index, 'Slot'] = None

# Now drop rows without NaN values
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```